# Preview site for Sitecore editors

Tags: sitecore, preview

Our content editors would like to have a preview site that would point to the master database. The site can be used to preview how the web page would look on the live site. The users aren't really comfortable using the 'Preview' option inside Sitecore. This site would point to the CMS server and be separate from the CMS site (used for content editing). The reason we can't use the CMS site to preview data is that HTML caching comes into play and content is not updated right away when a page is rendered.

By setting up a separate preview site, we plan to disable caching on this site and use it purely for content checking. I know there is a setting in the config files in sites section called "cacheHtml" which would be set to false in the config. My question is that is it safe to take the approach we are going with. Would turning off the HTML cache for the preview site cause any unwanted issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a valid approach. I have a blog post on it: [How to Setup a Sitecore Preview Site to Review Content Before Publishing](http://firebreaksice.com/how-to-setup-a-sitecore-preview-site-to-review-content-before-publishing/)

One thing to consider is if you have Lucene.NET indexes that would need to also be based on the master DB in addition to the web DB. You can see how to configure them for master and web here: [Configure Sitecore Search Index Support across Master and Web Databases](http://www.sitecoredevelopment.com/en/MarkUrsino/2012/December/Configure-Sitecore-Search-Index-Support-across-Master-and-Web-Databases.aspx)

Comment: I think we can get away with the content pointing to the master database.